# How to work with ido-vertical-mode inside dired-mode

Tags: emacs, dired, ido

For example, in the Dired window when I type <kbd>C</kbd> on a file called `test123.csv` under my `D:` drive, the minibuffer shows:

```
Copy test123.csv to d:/
->test123.csv
  hello.csv
```

If I type <kbd>RET</kbd> now, Emacs will say that it can't copy the file since it already exists. But what I need is to let it auto-complete to `d:\test123.csv` and then edit the file name to `d:\test123.back.csv`. But how to do it?

Comment: What did you do to enable `ido-vertical-mode` for `dired` commands?

Comment: great, how to disable the mode under dired? I knew M-X could do that. but how to do it in the initial file of .emacs

Comment: I think I know what you are trying to achieve; my question was not rhetorical :) I was asking because I can't reproduce the behavior you describe. When I press `C` on a file in `dired` after turning on `ido-vertical-mode` via `M-x ido-vertical-mode RET` I get the normal prompt that looks like this: `Copy <file> to: /path/to/current/directory/`. I do *not* get a list of possible completions.

Comment: I found I enabled ido everywhere, after I removed it from .emacs, now the problem is gone. thx

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. I am glad you were able to solve the problem yourself. However, while disabling `ido-everywhere` completely is a valid solution, you have other options. (Maybe you would like to keep using `ido-everywhere` in other contexts?) See my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mentioned in the comments that you are using `ido-vertical-mode` in conjunction with `ido-everywhere`. There are several things you can do:

- Completely disable `ido-everywhere` (as you suggested yourself) by removing

  ```
  (ido-everywhere)
  ```

  from your `.emacs` file.
- Disable `ido-everywhere` only for `dired` buffers:

  ```lisp
  (defun disable-ido-everywhere ()
    (ido-everywhere -1))
  (add-hook 'dired-mode-hook 'disable-ido-everywhere)
  ```
- Don't disable `ido-everywhere` at all and use the following workflow (which is very similar to what you would do without `ido-everywhere` enabled):

  1. Press <kbd>C</kbd>.
  2. Type the first few characters of the name of the file you want to copy followed by <kbd>TAB</kbd>. Repeat until file name has been completed fully (or up to a point at which it makes sense to start editing it).
  3. Edit the file name and press <kbd>RET</kbd> when done.